# No CJK in front matter after citing French bibliography entry

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, polyglossia, biblatex-chicago, xecjk

Creating a document

- using `xelatex`
- using `polyglossia` and French as another language
- using the package `xeCJK` for Chinese input
- using `biblatex-chicago` with `biber` (**it doesn’t happen with plain `biblatex`**)
- citing a source whose title is marked with `\begin{french}` and `\end{french}` in the .bib file

all entries in the table of contents, the list of figures and the list of tables will not show CJK characters **if added from a page after the citation** of the French title.

Simple solution: remove `\begin{french}`...`\end{french}` from the bibliography entry.
But why is that and what to do to keep the French title Frenchly hyphenated?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@book{frenchtitle,
    title = {\begin{french}Cela est un titre français\end{french}},
    location = {Paris},
    author = {Myers, Mike},
    date = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literature}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\section{Section title with CJK 永}
Some text.%
\autocite[][1]{frenchtitle}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This caption has CJK: 永}
\end{figure}

\section{Another section title with CJK 永}
Another Text 永.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The xecjk docu says that it is not fully compatible with polyglossia. Try with babel instead of polyglossia, imho its french module is more mature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn’t fix the bug described above, but it circumvents the problem altogether.
Instead of using a language environment (\begin{french}...\end{french}), use the `langid` field:

```
@book{frenchtitle,
    title = {Cela est un titre français},
    location = {Paris},
    author = {Myers, Mike},
    date = {2017},
    langid = {french}
}
```

The problem as described above doesn’t occur using `langid`.
And it is a lot more elegant and less time-consuming.
Not sure how I have been using LaTeX for all these years without learning about this field.